# Pages stored in MongoDB, accessible by mongo shell, but not tracked by git, and not visible when pushing to GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, mongodb, github, ckeditor

As the title says (and as it may be visible that I am still a beginner). In my rails app, I have implemented an MVC for support pages to my app.

I wanted to show the pages that I created to my mentor, so I committed and pushed to GitHub, but I noticed that only the images were pushed to GitHub! (I use CKeditor to handle images).

Now I am sure that the pages (that consists of a Title and Contents fields) exist, because when I execute the command `db.support_pages.find()` in the Mongo Shell, it gives me back a list of the pages with their contents and titles. But when I open those pages (localhost) and edit the content I see that git is not even tracking them!

I don't know what more information I should post, I will post the `.gitignore` file:

```
 *.rbc
*.sassc
*~
.sass-cache
.project
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle
/log/*
/tmp/*
/public/assets/*
/db/*.sqlite3
/public/system/*
/coverage/
/spec/tmp/*
/spec/coverage/*
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html
# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp
.idea
/attic/*
```

Any tips, leads, advice (or even queries to post more info regarding this issue) are welcomed. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @michaeltowfish Thank you for editing the post, It will be my example for the following post of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MongoDB database is composed of multiple data files containing the data and indexes.

If you want to commit the contents of the database to version control you will want to [export the data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/import-export/) and index definitions using `mongodump`.

If you want to share your database with your mentor, I would suggest using `mongodump` to get a full copy of the database, then compress and add that dump into git.

For example (on Linux) .. assuming a database called `mydatabase`:

```
cd ~/backup
mongodump -d mydatabase
tar -czvf mydatabase.tgz dump/
git add mydatabase.tgz
```

Your mentor would need to have MongoDB installed, and could extract the tgz file (`tar xzvf mydatabase.tgz`) and use `mongorestore` to load the data.  I expect your application might require future configuration, which you would document in a README.

Answer (score 1):

Git will track changes made in its directory. The pages you're talking about are stored in the database which is located somewhere else in your computer. We will need more information to give you some advice as to where you should dig.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: to make the pages visible not only locally, i mean when i access them from my machine, it's fine, but when i commited the newly created pages and pushed to github, there is only images, no pages at all.

Comment: right, as i said, i implemented an MVC to create those "wiki" or "blog-like" pages, they consist of text with images, when i view them using localhost, they are working perfectly, but when i commited and pushed, there are "only" the images that i used ckeditor to uplad. and the pages are not exist on github.

Comment: That's because you will never get to see the content of your local database on Github

Comment: yes right, but i mean after pushing, when i choose the commits tab on github, and see the commit details, it doesn't show any thing about the text or the "pages" it only shows the images that ckeditor uploaded

Comment: yes, CkEditro does store the photos, but the text is stored in different model.